# Does Lightning Web Component IF Directive support multiple conditions?

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

Hi I am new to LWC world & its syntax.
I wanted to ask, if LWC supports multiple condition in a single statement?

Ex:

```
<template if:true={condition1 == 'value1' && condition2 == 'value2'}></template>
```

Getting Error on using multiple conditions on single line statement.

or
should go for below approach

```
html - <template if:true={validateCondition}></template>
class js file - get validateCondition() { return (condition1 == 'value1' && condition2 == 'value2');}
```

Or have to use nested conditions

```
<template if:true={condition1 == 'value1'}>
  <template if:true={condition2 == 'value2'}>
  </template>
</template>
```

Current using above statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 2. Keep html clean. The decisions to show/hide parts of page are part of your business logic, should be kept in JS with other calculations. That'd also make it testable. I don't think you even can do option 3, I expect it to fail on compilation?

You can't use formulas in these or anything computed, only straight properties and getters. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_directives

Migration guide might help too: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.migrate_expressions

Answer to this one is cool too: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/249293/799

Comment: Option 3 working. Thanks for clarifying option 2 approach.